# Searching in Vim for string with period (dot) in it

Tags: regex, search, vim

I see many similar questions to this here but they don't seem to answer mine. I'd like to search (and, ultimately, replace) a string with a period character in the middle of it - eg

```
like.this
```

Most of the similar answers tell me to use the backslash to escape the . character, but 
`:s/like\.this` does not work, and nor does `:s/\like.this`. Could anyone please tell me if there's something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:s` is only looking in the current line, try something like:

```
:%s/like\.this/bar/g
```

where, `%s` means to search all strings, and you replace `like.this` with `bar`.

Comment: Yeah... this is an embarassing one. Thanks for the non-patronizing correction.